# cpuid function 0Bh, intel, always empty registers

Tags: assembly, x86, cpuid

On both, Linux (as root) and Windows (XP, as admin) I always get an empty registers set after calling cpuid with eax = 0xB.
According to official manual, http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-identification-cpuid-instruction-note.html I wrote the following code:

```
mov eax,0xb
xor ecx,ecx
cpuid
; EAX = EBX = ECX = EDX = 0
```

I have successfully written AMD cpuinfo based on 'cpuid' instruction just before this, but intel's 0xb function just won't work. tried on two available intel computers with no luck. What am I missing here?

Comment: intel manual pdf, page 41-42 (5.1.12)

Comment: Does the system have X2APIC? Does it have more than one thread or core? Is this a virtual machine?

Comment: So it is not supported.  There isn't anything in your question that suggests your processor does support it.

Comment: sorry, there wasn't anything mentioned about it can be unsupported in that manual section. test boxes had  Atom N455(Linux real box), and Intel Celeron Dual Core T3100 (Linux real box and Windows in virtualbox).

Comment: i've been trying to gather info on real processor cores count. am i going the wrong way doing it with cpuid? i need something could be used on windows, beginning from such old monsters as 2000.

Comment: @Hans Passant: you were right, that method is not supported on those CPUs. i found an older method which is absolutely wrong on i7 box(however i7 supports the x2apic so that helps), returning 16 on 4-core CPU. this is in function 0x1, in ebx bits 23:16. guess i have a choice of using info provided by windows or die.

Answer (score -1):

check the feature availability first, see the manual, 5.1.2, function 01.

however this does not answer the question of enumerating actual CPU cores which was my intention. if someone is not lazy, please share your findings on this topic in comments, thank you.